# how do i send parameters using my android app to a remote server using JSON. the code is given below

Tags: java, android, json

i am using a reference code for testing ,but when i run the app and click the submit button it shows "Unfortunately your app has Stopped".
Here is my java.class

```
package com.internship.mtslogin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class fpasswd extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText email ;
private Button  msubmit;

 // Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script

//localhost :  
//testing on your device
//put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
//or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
private static final String LOGIN_URL ="http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/register.php";



//testing from a real server:
//private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/register.php";

//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forgot_passwd);



    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);




    msubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    msubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(fpasswd.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait, Registering");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;

        String emailid = email.getText().toString();


        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailid));



            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script 
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());                
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(fpasswd.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}


}
```

But when i run it in a localhost it works fine.

the parameters to be send is only "email".
and url in which i am doing is real server.
i have removed the real url and put a dummy url for string passing.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

here is the logcat details.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3    
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET      permission?)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
```

Comment: post your logcat plz!

Comment: window > open perspective > other > Logcat

Comment: you can edit your question in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the error message.  You are missing INTERNET permission.  Add to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

well it looks like you dont have access to the internet.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET      permission?)
```

Add this line to the AndroidMainfest.xml to enable the Internet access.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```